# What do the BMW engine naming conventions represent?

Tags: bmw

I have always assumed the BMW vehicle naming conventions represented the engine size, e.g. a **BMW 118d** suggests it's a 1 series model with a 1.8 litre diesel engine and similarly a **320i** suggests it's a 3 series model with a 2.0 litre petrol engine.

But then they throw a **123d** into the mix and the pattern doesn't quite follow. What does the 123 mean? Is it related to BHP? Twin turbo?

Can anyone shed some light onto this or provide a list of engine sizes and their meanings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically the numbers used to indicate the displacement of the engine, exactly as you describe in the question. As the engine technology has moved more away from being naturally-aspirated petrols across the range the numbers became more of a suggestion of the "equivalent" performace that the engine provided. This is really only an approximation - the rule of thumb that the higher the two numbers the more powerful the engine is really what you need to bear in mind.

To use your examples a 118d is actually a 2.0 turbocharged diesel engine, the 120d is the same engine mapped to produce more power and a 123d is a 2.0 diesel with twin turbochargers.

"i" is indicating that it is a petrol engine, "d" is diesel.